# Move up a text in equations

Tags: equations, line-spacing

I don't know if the title explains much what I want to say, but here it is:

```
$$ \frac{\text{XXXXX }}{\text{YYYYYYYY}} \text{(ZZZZZZZZZZZZ)} $$
```

I want to move up the ZZZZ sentence so that it is aligned with XXXX.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please: **Don't use `$$`**! Use `\[...\]` instead. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to

Comment: What are the `\displaystyle` directives meant to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear what you're asking, but it seems you're abusing math mode:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
XXXXX \\
\hline
YYYYYYYY
\end{tabular}
(ZZZZZZZZZZZZ)
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks It's exactly what i want to do.
How i can do it in a proper way?

Answer (score 2):

If you want it in math mode, you can use `array`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{cc}
\text{XXXXX}    & \text{(ZZZZZZZZZZZZ)} \\\cline{1-1}
\text{YYYYYYYY}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]